# How to get VB.net 3.5 app to interface with a USB scale

Tags: vb.net, usb

I have a Mettler Toledo postal scale (PS60) that I need to configure and read weights from using a USB connection. The scale uses the Microsoft USB POS HID for scales driver. I will have 11 to 12 of these scales connected, and will need to identify each as well. The idea being my users will remove something from one scale and place it on another, I need to make sure they do so from the correct scales.

I've not done any work with USB development and I'm struggling to get started. Are there some examples or documentation that will help me get up to speed?

Summary of what I need to do:

- Detect scales connecting and disconnecting
- Send configuration commands to each individual scale
- Detect changes in stable weight on each scale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://github.com/nricciar/usb_scale for a c# example for getting data from a PS60 scale.  I just wrote it this morning though, so beware.

Comment: I converted this to VB.net and added some events and properties. Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the scale vendor and ask them how they publish data from their hardware for automated systems to use.  They might have an api, if you're lucky.